# Can I install ConsoleZ without a package manager?

Tags: windows-7, terminal, console, console2

I am not sure why/how, but I can't seem to simply install ConsoleZ on my Windows 7 computer. I went [here](https://github.com/cbucher/console/releases), got the latest x64 release, and unzipped it.

Afer unzipping it, I get just one directory, that looks like this

[image: directory listing]

Now I simply double click on Console.exe. This, however, gives me a very 'boring' looking console, and actually says 'Console2' at the top, not ConsoleZ. This is the first point that confuses me... what is going on here? The other .exe (ConsoleWow) doesn't run anything if I click it.

---

So I Googled around some more, and found that I can get ConsoleZ, but from a package manager called 'Chocolatey'. This is from [here](http://chocolatey.org/packages/ConsoleZ/1.10.0.14089). I have not tried that yet, (should I have to?), but this is another possible way. But I do not understand how/why my first attempt from above doesnt work. Where is the 'ConsoleZ'??

Comment: 'Boring looking'? Try ConEmu.

Answer (score 4):

ConsoleZ is just a fork of Console2:

> This is a modified version of Console 2 for a better experience under Windows Vista/7/8 and a better visual rendering. Built packages are available here: 
>   https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki/Downloads

Most likely, the changes were minor and just for a better user experience and didnt bother changing the names of files or titles.

As for your "bunch of files," thats how Console2 was packaged - no installer.

Comment: Thanks Keltari - so then this ConsoleZ was 'installed' correctly, and even though it says 'Console2' when I run it, it is really just running ConsoleZ? Also - why is there that ConsoleWow.exe? Why does nothing happen when I run it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ConsoleWow.exe` is 32-bit helper module. For internal use of `Console.exe`. User must not (and can not) run it directly.

P.S. Purpose of that module - infiltrate 32-bit shells from 64-bit `Console.exe`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try your ConEmu tomorrow. I just want something similar to iTerm2. Will it be possible for me to 1) specify hotkeys for how to split panes, 2) specify hotkeys for navigation? Also, (I am a noob at this stuff), but would I be able to use linux commands in it? Thanks!

Comment: 1 - yes, 2 - yes. "Linux commands" are not a `terminal` feature! Wondering, why not to install them? On of the dozen packages available for years: Cygwin, msys, msysgit, unxutils, babun, ... Terminal - is "terminal", it is just a "display" for console applications!

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the installer via this link here. [x64 installer](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html). Before that however, I tried to unzip the latest from your github [here](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/releases), however there seems to be an error when unzipping. I think I have it installed now... let me try to set it up... is it possible to make it always start on gitBash? Thanks

Comment: Your conEmu is very nice... one question, how do you make the scroller bar NEVER appear? Sometimes when I go from one split panel to another, the scroller appears for that panel... how do I stop this? Thanks.

Comment: GitHub does not provide binaries download service. All you can download from github directly - is sources! There is (on the project page) LARGE green button named "Download". All binaries, packages and installers are there.
Want gitbash on startup? Choose it on Settings\Startup page.
Open Settings dialog and type "scroll" in the "Find" edit box, disable scroll. And take a look at existing questions here.